# d2: strange lowering of protection and possible misbehavior in static imports

Tags: d

Consider there is `moda.d`:

```
module moda;

private struct modb {};
```

And `modb.d`:

```
module modb;

private import moda;
```

And `modmain.d`:

```
module modmain;

static import moda;
static import modb;

void main() {
    modb v; // should NOT compile, should it?
}
```

I don't know why, but `moda.modb` is visible in both `modmain` and `modb`, while, as far as I understand, it should not - both due to `moda` being imported as `static` and `moda.modb` being `private`. Or should? Have I run into dmd bug or it's planned behaviour I hadn't understood?

**Update1:** I performed some tests, to determine under which circumstances bug replicates.

First column is for `import moda`, second for `import modb`, third is identifier used as struct name. All of there tests should fail compilation, but some compile.

Legend: D - "import module;", S - "static import module;", N - no import.

> D;D;foobar - compiles due to bug #2830
>
> S;D;foobar - fails as expected
>
> N;D;foobar - fails as expected
>
> D;S;foobar - compiles due to bug #2830
>
> S;S;foobar - fails as expected
>
> N;S;foobar - fails as expected
>
> D;N;foobar - compiles due to bug #2830
>
> S;N;foobar - fails as expected
>
> N;N;foobar - fails as expected
>
> D;D;moda - compiles due to bug #2830
>
> **S;D;moda - should not compile**
>
> **N;D;moda - should not compile**
>
> D;S;moda - compiles due to bug #2830
>
> **S;S;moda - should not compile**
>
> N;S;moda - fails as expected
>
> D;N;moda - compiles due to bug #2830
>
> **S;N;moda - should not compile**
>
> N;N;moda - fails as expected
>
> D;D;modb - compiles due to bug #2830
>
> **S;D;modb - should not compile**
>
> **N;D;modb - should not compile**
>
> D;S;modb - compiles due to bug #2830
>
> **S;S;modb - should not compile**
>
> **N;S;modb - should not compile**
>
> D;N;modb - compiles due to bug #2830
>
> S;N;modb - fails as expected
>
> N;N;modb - fails as expected

Seems that if some module's name is the same as non-exposed symbol, it's being exposed regardless of protection level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've [filled a bug #7856](http://d.puremagic.com/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=7856#c0) for this sort of behavior.

Answer (score 1):

It's [bug# 2830](http://d.puremagic.com/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=2830) and has nothing to do with static imports. You'd get the same problem regardless of whether you use static or not. And the module modb has nothing to do with it either. You could remove it entirely and still get the same situation.

Also some side notes about your code:

1. Putting a ; at the end of a struct or class declaration like that is unnecessary in D.
2. private on imports does nothing. They're automatically private.
3. Naming symbols the same as module names can result in having to give full import paths when using them. It's not as big a problem if you use multiple levels of packages (e.g. a.b.c wouldn't cause you to have to use the full path when using c, whereas a.a generally would need to be used as a.a instead of a), but if you only have one level of packages, it's going to cause problems. Typically module names are all lowercase, whereas type names are PascalCase, and variable and function names are camelCase, in which case you don't run into those sort of problems much (i.e. only when you have a single level of packages and you have a camelCased symbol which is only one word long). So following more typical D naming conventions helps avoid the problem. It also tends to be what other D programmers expect, but that obviously varies depending on the programmer. It *is* what the standard library does though.

Comment: Thank you, Jonathan. Initially struct was incomplete, so `;` was mandatory - I simplified code sample by making struct complete. Private on import was put to explicitly exclude possibility of `public import` - I know that all imports are `private` by default. And I've run into this problem when porting interface to C library, so I preserved naming convention.

Comment: Also, removing modb makes code do not compile - so it's **not** bug #2830. I've updated question to reflect changes.

Comment: It's not compiling, because you're using a static import rather than a normal one. With a static import, a symbol must be fully qualified. If you remove the static, it will compiled without the module modb in spite of the fact that the type modb is private (your choice of names is quite poor and confusing, using modb for different stuff in separate modules). I don't know why adding the modb module would fix this, but it may be related to bug 314: http://d.puremagic.com/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=314 Regardless, bug# 2830 makes it so that private structs can still be constructed.

Comment: It's clearly a combination of bugs - including both #2830 and #314. It may or may not really constitute a new bug, but it doesn't hurt to report it as a new one.